# Character of a non-compact topological group is not $L^2?$

Tags: fourier-analysis, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

I think this result is used in something I am reading though it's not completely clear to me. I am not very sure that if it's true, it should be. The statement is the following:

**A nontrivial character of a non-compact abelian group is not in $L^2$.**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A character is a map into the unit circle (right?), so it has absolute value 1 everywhere. Since $G$ is not compact, it's Haar measure is $\infty$. Combining these facts, what do you get?

Comment: @PhoemueX, usually a character is defined as map into $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, for finite group the image turns out to be the unit circle. Is it so for any group ?

Comment: No, this does not follow automatically. Just consider the map $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}, x \mapsto e^x$. The statement you want to prove should hold nevertheless, however.